How may I get an unlimited array of parameters, to be checked with ifundefined?
\def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax {\bf #1} is undefined \vskip0.5\baselineskip \else {\bf #1} is defined  \vskip0.5\baselineskip\fi} %

{\bf First example:}

\ifundefined{hour}
\newcount\hours
\ifundefined{hours}

{\bf Second example:}

\def\definecheck#1#2{
\ifundefined{#1}
\ifundefined{#2}
....
}
\newcount\down
\definecheck{top}{down}

{\bf Question:}

How may I get an unlimited array of parameters, to be checked with ifundefined?
%example
%\definecheck{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m}
\bye


First off, your \ifundefined macro is not really good: a call
\ifundefined{hours}

would result in \hours being equivalent to \relax, so not really “undefined”. You want
\def\ifundefined#1{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    {\bf #1} is undefined \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \else
    {\bf #1} is defined  \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \fi
}

because when \csname...\endcsname results in a previously undefined token, this token is made equivalent to \relax. By using a group, this equivalence will disappear as soon as the group ends.
If you use pdftex (as opposed to Knuth TeX), then
\def\ifundefined#1{%
  \ifcsname #1\endcsname
    {\bf #1} is defined \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \else
    {\bf #1} is undefined  \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \fi
}

would be safer, because \ifcsname doesn't make the token equivalent to \relax.
Here's the code for \defcheck as you want.
\def\ifundefined#1{%
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
    {\bf #1} is undefined \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \else
    {\bf #1} is defined  \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \fi
}

\def\definecheck#1{\definecheckaux#1,,}
\def\definecheckaux#1,{%
  \def\next{#1}%
  \ifx\next\empty
    \let\next\relax
  \else
    \ifundefined{#1}%
    \let\next\definecheckaux
  \fi
  \next
}


{\bf First example:}

\ifundefined{hours}
\ifundefined{hours}
\newcount\hours
\ifundefined{hours}

{\bf Second example:}

\definecheck{top,down}

\definecheck{alpha,bbeta,gamma,delte}

\bye



What is wrong with \def\ifundefined#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax {\bf #1} is undefined \vskip0.5\baselineskip \else {\bf #1} is defined  \vskip0.5\baselineskip\fi}

\ifundefined{hours}
would result in \hours being equivalent to \relax, so not really “undefined”.  Why that?

@MBE If you do \csname foo\endcsname (when \foo has no definition), from then on (but respecting grouping) \foo becomes equivalent to \relax. TeXbook, exercise 7.7 on page 40.

So what is the problem? An undefined defintion is supposed to do nothing and is stil reported as undefined and may be redefined.

well for example @MBE with your suggested version \ifundefined{relax} will be true and if you then go on to define \relax  a lot of tex code will break, including your definition of \ifundefined

@David Carlisle
Truly, I do not understand. Why do I get an "undefined" by testing \relax, even if it is defined as a primitive?

Suppose that we want to do a historical exploration using the ancient TeX. Then note that \begingroup \expandafter\endgroup \expandafter\ifx \csname#1\edcsname \undefined is more simple and it is able to distinguish between undefined and \relax.

@MBE your code does not testify something is undefined,  it tests if its csname is relax. See wipet's comment for a version that tests for undefined, as long as you never define the test token \undefined

If using 3rd party code is fine you could load expkv1 (disclaimer: I'm the author of expkv), it has everything you need (but requires e-TeX with the \expanded primitive, so is not Knuthian TeX):
\input{expkv}

% borrow some internal macro to check if a csname is defined
\catcode`@=11
\def\ifundefined#1%
  {{\bf #1} is \ekv@ifdefined{#1}{}{un}defined\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\catcode`@=12

\def\definecheck{\ekvcsvloop\ifundefined}

example
\definecheck{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m}
\bye


1 expkv is a package that provides key=value parsing as its core functionality, this answer uses only a byproduct of its implementation.

A dependency free version. It reimplements the csv-loop and defined check. Note that unlike expkv this version only works for , of a single category code (expkv works for mixed categories of 12 and 13 for ,).
\catcode`@=11
% small auxiliaries
\long\def\@gobble#1{}
\long\def\@gobbletwo#1#2{}
\long\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\long\def\@thirdofthree#1#2#3{#3}
\long\def\@gobbletostop#1\@stop{}

% check if a csname is defined
% #1 should be the tokens forming the csname if used as `\csname#1\endcsname`
% #2 what should be done if it is defined (and not \relax)
% #3 what should be done if it is undefined or \relax
\long\def\myifdefined#1%
  {%
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    \@thirdofthree{\myifdefined@{#1}}%
  }
\long\def\myifdefined@#1%
  {%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
      \expandafter\@thirdofthree
    \fi
    \@firstoftwo
  }

% trim a space from either end of the input and apply some code to it. The
% result is left inside of \unexpanded.
% #1 should be the code.
% #2 should be the stuff you want trim spaces from (with a \mymark in front of
%    it, shouldn't contain another \mymark or \@stop outside of braces)
\def\mytrimapply#1{%
\long\def\mytrimapply##1##2%
  {%
    \mytrimapply@a##2\@stop\mymark#1#1\@stop{##1}%
  }
\long\def\mytrimapply@a##1\mymark#1{\mytrimapply@b##1\mymark}
\long\def\mytrimapply@b##1#1\@stop{\mytrimapply@c##1\@stop}
\long\def\mytrimapply@c\mymark##1\@stop##2\@stop##3{\unexpanded{##3{##1}}}
}
\mytrimapply{ }

% loop arbitrary code over the contents of a comma separated list. Each list
% element will be stripped of surrounding spaces and a single set of outer
% braces (after space stripping), blank elements are ignored.
% #1 the code that should expect each list element as a following argument in {}
% #2 the comma separated list of values (elements must not contain the tokens
% \mymark and \@stop outside of any braces)
\long\def\mycsvloop#1#2%
  {%
    \mycsvloop@{#1}\mymark#2,\@stop\mycsvloop@end,%
  }
\long\def\mycsvloop@#1#2,%
  {%
    \@gobbletostop#2\@stop
    \mycsvloop@notblank{#2}%
    \mytrimapply{#1}{#2}%
    \mycsvloop@{#1}\mymark
  }
\long\def\mycsvloop@end#1\mycsvloop@#2\mymark{}
\long\def\mycsvloop@notblank#1%
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobbletwo#1.}\relax
      \mycsvloop@blank
    \fi
  }
\def\mycsvloop@blank\fi#1\mycsvloop@{\fi\mycsvloop@}
\catcode`@=12


\def\ifundefined#1%
  {{\bf #1} is \myifdefined{#1}{}{un}defined\vskip.5\baselineskip}

\def\definecheck{\mycsvloop\ifundefined}

{\bf Example}

\definecheck{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m}
\bye


I like this, only I do not want to input whole packages, if they are not really needed.  Packages are fine, but I like to keep it as simple as possible.

It is much more simple to check \aplha instead alpha because you need not to construct control sequences by \csname...\endcsame and you need not to solve the obscure behavior of TeX: setting undefined control sequences to \relax when it is constructed by \csname...\endcsname.
I suggest to do this:
\def\isundefined#1{%
   {\tt\string#1} is
   \ifx#1\undefined un\fi
   defined\medskip 
}
\def\definecheck#1{\ifx#1;\else \isundefined#1 \expandafter\definecheck\fi}

\definecheck \alpha\beta\gamma\delta
   \WizardofOz\MyAunt\Retriever\Fox \wolf
   \supercalifragilisticexpialidocious ;

\bye

Or use names without backslash but forgot the limitations of classical TeX (which is not used many decades and it is run only if somebody needs to do a historical exploration). It means that the construction \begingroup ...\endgroup...\ifx... is ancient and definitely not used today. From 1992, we can use \ifcsname TeX primitive instead of this (the second egreg's variant). It means 32 years.
\def\ifundedfined#1{%
   {\bf #1} is
   \ifcsname #1\endcsname \else un\fi
   defined\medskip
}


Thanks for fixing my code!

I see your point about e-TeX but (1) I'd say it's been usable since 1999 (when it was finalised) and (2) for the true believer in the Knuth approach, pre-e-TeX methods are still needed :)

@wipet "It means 32 years." Some drive cars even older.

Yes, but people should know that the construction \begingroup ...\ifx.csname ...\relax is intended to veteran cars and it is not used in today's TeX.

@wipet
Absolutely right. But I ask you to give me a hint: What is "today's TeX" and what is "yesterday's  TeX"? Was it not Knuth's precondition, that the original program should not be altered or developed and should produce the same output in a hundred years? So, is it not reasonable, to expect and keep "yesterdays TeX" functioning and useable....and known?

This is opinion based discussion. IMHO, the Knuths decision about frozen TeX, Metafont and CM fonts has very low usability today. Of course, we can create the same documents today as before 40 years ago using the historical TeX (still included in common TeX distributions), but these documents must have only text in Computer Modern font. No graphics and similar things. Only few old documents meet this. If you use different than Computer modern 7bit font today (this is very common in today's documents) then you cannot suppose that the document will be processed in the same way in 50 years.

@MBE Yes for 'TeX' but DEK allowed derivates to be produced. Of those, pdfTeX (which adds PDF output and the e-TeX extensions) is the most widely used today, and it is 100% backward compatible with Knuth's TeX: so it's still 8-bit. LuaTeX isn't 100% compatible (see e.g. hyphenating first word in a box), but is Unicode-based and offers many advantages - and almost all 'classical' TeX constructs still work just the same.
